# Getting access to URL changes in an iframe

Tags: jquery, url, dom, iframe, parent

I have some existing JavaScript code, that I cannot change, that is loaded into an iframe.  The initial page that is in the iframe is a local page but the links (actually `<input type="button"...>`'s) from the JavaScript go to external content.  I am looking for a way to make changes to the main page that the iframe is in when the button in the iframe is clicked to go to the external URL.

Can I get access to the local page css classes inside the iframe somehow?  Failing that, can .unload() be used in place of .click?  I have only managed to use .unload to capture page changes in the parent frame.

```
<iframe name="venueFrame" id="venueFrame" frameBorder="0" src=""><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
<script>
    function selectVenue(page){
        compleateURL='venuemaps/'+page;
        document.getElementById('venueShadow').style.display="block";
        $("#venueFrame").attr({src:compleateURL});
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know without seeing any code, but you can bind to a click on the iframe by doing

```
$('#iframe').bind('click', function(e) {
    //Stuff to do
});
```

This will happen whenever anything inside the iframe is clicked.  If you're trying to change something specific based on the links, you're going to have a very difficult time doing that.